# My JavaScript timer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, web, timer

Im trying to create a small JavaScript timer in which a user has a limited amount of time to answer a question, and if the user does not answer in time, they will be directed back to the main page. All I get back from my code in terms of the timer is literally "   [ ]    ".

My code:

```
    <DOCTYPE! html>

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_q1.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

var time="60";
var min="0";
var sec="0";

function startTimer() {
      min=parseInt(timer/60);
      sec=parseInt(timer%60);

      if(timer<1){

        window.location="index.html";

      }

      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<b> Time Left: </b>"+min.toString()+":"+sec.toString();
      timer--;
      setTimeout(function(){
      startTimer();
      }, 1000) ;
}

</script>


</head>

<body onload="startTimer();">

  <div id="top">


  </div>


  <div id="logo">

<h1 style="color:white;"> Question 1 -  Geography </h1>

  </div>

  <div id="game_area">

 <center>  <h2> What is the capital of Ireland? </h2> </center>



  </div>


  <div id="time">

      <center> <b>[<span id="time" ></span></b>]</center>

  </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 body tags?

Comment: You don't define `timer` anywhere.

Comment: I fixed the body FrankerZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note:

- `<!DOCTYPE>` instead of `<DOCTYPE!>`
- id attributes should be unique, you have two declared
- `<center>` is deprecated. Find a solution using CSS.
- Rather than adding an `onload` attribute to your `<body>` I would suggest adding an `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to your document.

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_q1.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">

      function startTimer() {
          min = parseInt(timer / 60);
          sec = parseInt(timer % 60);

          if (timer < 1) {
              window.location = "index.html";
          }

          document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<b> Time Left: </b>" + min.toString() + ":" + sec.toString();
          timer--;
          setTimeout(function () {
              startTimer();
          }, 1000);
      }

      var timer = 60,
          min = 0,
          sec = 0;

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          startTimer();
      });
  </script>
  ```

  Question 1 - Geography

  ### What is the capital of Ireland?

  **[**]

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), it's pretty much designed for this:

**UPDATE:**  Remember to stop the setinterval process when the time is up.
Use this method [`clearInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) to stop the process.

```js
var secondsLeft = 60;

function startTimer() {
      var min=parseInt(secondsLeft/60);
      var sec=parseInt(secondsLeft%60);

      if(secondsLeft<1){
        alert('timer expired');

        //window.location="index.html";

      }

      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<b> Time Left: </b>"+min.toString()+":"+sec.toString();
      secondsLeft--;
}

setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_q1.css">
</head>

<body onload="startTimer();">

  <div id="top">


  </div>


  <div id="logo">

    <h1 style="color:white;"> Question 1 -  Geography </h1>

  </div>

  <div id="game_area">

 <center>  <h2> What is the capital of Ireland? </h2> </center>



  </div>
  <div id="time">

      <center> <b>[<span id="time" ></span></b>]</center>

  </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: I think would be nice to mention that OP will need to stop the setInterval process using the method `clearInterval`.

Comment: Well, he wrote `window.location = 'blah'`, so that timer is going to be done as soon as the page redirects.

Comment: Yes, but it's important to mention for future users using the same scenario with SPA.  Of course, if you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

spelling mistake

> rename time to timer

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_q1.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

var timer="60";
var min="0";
var sec="0";


function startTimer() {
      min=parseInt(timer/60);
      sec=parseInt(timer%60);

      if(timer<1){

        window.location="index.html";

      }

      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<b> Time Left: </b>"+min.toString()+":"+sec.toString();
      timer--;
      setTimeout(function(){
      startTimer();
      }, 1000) ;
}

</script>


</head>

<body onload="startTimer();">

  <div id="top">


  </div>


  <div id="logo">

<h1 style="color:white;"> Question 1 -  Geography </h1>

  </div>

  <div id="game_area">

 <center>  <h2> What is the capital of Ireland? </h2> </center>



  </div>
  <body onload="startTimer();">

  <div id="time">

      <center> <b>[<span id="time" ></span></b>]</center>

  </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your code has an error with the variable `time`
- You can use setInterval to accomplish your scenario.
- Remember to stop the setinterval process when the time is up.

```js
var timer = 10;
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
var refreshIntervalId;

function startTimer() {
      min=parseInt(timer / 60);
      sec=parseInt(timer % 60);

      if (timer < 1) {
        //window.location="index.html";
        console.log("Time is up!");
        
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        
        return;
      }

      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<b> Time Left: </b>" + min + ":" + sec;
      
      timer--;
}

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="top">
  </div>
  <div id="logo">
<h1 style="color:white;"> Question 1 -  Geography </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="game_area">
 <center>  <h2> What is the capital of Ireland? </h2> </center>
  </div>
  <div id="time">
  <center> <b>[<span id="time" ></span></b>]</center>
</div>
```

**Hope it helps!**